# Remove postmeta from post edit

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am working with a custom post type in Wordpress to represent accomodations that can be rented per weeks. I have added a metabox for the administrator to add new bookings, which also has the calendar, and a list of current bookings.

There is a delete button on each booking in the list and what I want to do is, when the user clicks this button (after a confirmation message), reload the page and just delete this booking (which by the way is a postmeta). I don't want to use Ajax as it would make much more difficult to reload some other contents from the form.

For this, I send via the delete link the id of the postmeta to be deleted and a parameter 'my_action' with value 'deleteBooking'. Then, from a method hooked to  'init' action hook I check parameter 'my_action' and if it is 'deleteBooking' I call the method which deletes the postmeta.

The deletion works fine, the problem is, after this, the edit page is not reloaded (I just get a blank page).

My questions are:

is it right to check 'my_action' parameter and call deleteBooking from a method hooked to 'init'? Is there a more appropriate hook for this kind of action?

How should I redirect the action for the application to reload the edit page refershing its contents?

I am thinking on using a checkbox for each booking in the list instead of a link, and delete checked bookings from a method hooked to 'save_post' when the user submits the post edition, but I would prefer the other approach. If anyone has any advice it will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would check you php syntax and your error logs.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, if you took the checkbox approach, and run the deleteBooking code on the save_post action, for each booking that was checked, then your redirect problem would solve itself. It is a little more work, but also a little better, because of two reasons.

1. It solves your redirecting/reloading problem
2. It is more user-friendly to allow a multi-delete using checkboxes, than it is to require them to click a delete link for every booking

Hope this helps